# How to change the chart title width to match slide width in python-pptx?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Hi I have simple code which generates one ppt slide like below but the slide title width is smaller than slide width? how can I increase the title width ?

[image]

```
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()
prs.slide_width = Inches(16)
prs.slide_height = Inches(9)
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[5]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title

title.text = "This is test slide.This is test slide.This is test slide.This is test slide.This is test slide.This is test slide"
title.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = Pt(20)

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Comment: The standard size for a wide-screen presentation is 13.33" by 7.5", not 16"x9".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position and size of the slide title is normally determined by the slide layout. In this case you seem to have chosen the one layout which does not have a title shape.

I would start by using a different slide layout, like `slide_layouts[1]` and see if the title isn't closer to what you want.

The benefit of using the slide layout for that job is that all slides created with that layout have a consistently positioned and formatted title with no extra work on your part. It also has benefits for when you change templates.

Otherwise, if you really want to adjust the size in a particular case, `slide.shapes.title` is a shape, and has `.left`, `.top`, `.width`, and `.height` properties like any other shapes.

Comment: thanks scanny for helping on pptx stuff.. actually i am looking for slide with title only so i thought layout 5 is correct one

Comment: .width and .height worked for me with layout 5.. thanks :)